Animation classes appyling on scroll when each section fully shown on the screen
I am facing a problem, and I used ChatGPT a lot. But didn't get the solution.
I have few section in my template.
section1
section2
section3
section4
section5.

I want that each section visible 90% once on scroll (should be response two). I want to apply a specific animation classes.
I didn't a lot from my side.
Here is my current code on scroll:
 window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
      // I am checking that i am at the top of the div-3 or not ?
      const _section: any = document.getElementById('div-3');
      const _sectionTop: any = _section.offsetTop;
      const _sectionBottom: any = _sectionTop + _section.offsetHeight;
      const _scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;

      // Check if the top of the section is in view
      if (_scrollPosition >= _sectionTop && window.scrollY < _sectionBottom) {
          console.log('I am at the top of the div-3 section!');
          div6.style.display = 'block';
          div7.style.display = 'none';
      } else {
        console.log('Not I am not at the top of the div-3 section.');
      }

      // --------- DIV 4 ---------
      // ------ Statistics -------
      // -------------------------
      const scrollPosition = window.scrollY + window.innerHeight;
      const div4Start = div3.offsetTop;
      let expandThreshold = div4Start - (window.innerHeight * 0.1);

      if (scrollPosition >= expandThreshold) {
        div4.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((card: any) => {
          // Add animation classes again
          card.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__zoomIn');
          // Remove animation classes after animation ends
          card.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
            card.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__zoomIn');
          }, { once: true });
        });
      } else {
        div4.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach((card: any) => {
          // Add animation classes again
          card.classList.remove('animate__animated', 'animate__zoomIn');
        });
      }

      // -------- DIV 6 --------
      // A Legacy of Exploration
      // -----------------------
      const div6Headings: any = document.getElementById('div-6-headings');
      const div6Start = div6.offsetTop;
      expandThreshold = div6Start - window.innerHeight * 0.1;
      if (scrollPosition >= expandThreshold) {
        // Trigger the class removal and margin change after a delay or an event
        setTimeout(() => {
          globe.classList.add('globe-animate');
          setTimeout(() => {
            map.style.display = 'block';
            div6Headings.style.display = 'block';
            map.classList.add('animate__zoomIn');
            div6Headings.classList.add('animate__fadeIn');
          }, 800);
        }, 800); // Start after 1 second (adjust timing as needed)

      } else {
        map.style.display = 'none';
        div6Headings.style.display = 'none';

        map.classList.remove('animate__zoomIn');
        globe.classList.remove('globe-animate');
        div6Headings.classList.remove('animate__fadeIn');
      }

      // -------- DIV 7 --------
      // A Gateway to Growth
      // -----------------------
      const div7Headings: any = document.getElementById('div-7-headings');
      const div7Start = div7.offsetTop;
      expandThreshold = div7Start - window.innerHeight * 0.01;
      if (scrollPosition >= expandThreshold) {
      } else {
      }

      // --------- DIV 8 ---------
      // Unlock Untapped Potential
      // -------------------------
      const div8: any = document.getElementById('div-8');
      const div8Headings: any = document.getElementById('div-8-headings');
      const div8Start = div8.offsetTop;
      expandThreshold = div8Start - window.innerHeight * 0.1;
      if (scrollPosition >= expandThreshold) {
        div6.style.display = 'none';

        div7.classList.add('animate__animated', 'animate__fadeIn');
        div7.style.display = 'block';

        map2.classList.add('animate__zoomIn');
        div7Headings.classList.add('animate__slideInUp');
      } else {
        map2.classList.remove('animate__zoomIn');
        div7Headings.classList.remove('animate__slideInUp');
        // div8Headings.classList.remove('animate__slideInRight');
      }

      // -------- DIV 9 ---------
      // Eligibility Requirements
      // ------------------------
      const div9: any = document.getElementById('div-9');
      const div9Headings: any = document.getElementById('div-9-headings');
      const div9Start = div9.offsetTop;
      expandThreshold = div9Start - window.innerHeight * 0.1;
      if (scrollPosition >= expandThreshold) {
        // Trigger the class removal and margin change after a delay or an event
        setTimeout(() => {
          div8Headings.classList.add('animate__slideInRight');
          div9Headings.classList.add('animate__slideInRight');
        }, 250); // Start after 1 second (adjust timing as needed)
      } else {
        div8Headings.classList.remove('animate__slideInRight');
        div9Headings.classList.remove('animate__slideInRight');
      }
    });


Adding an example on stackblitz or another similar platform would be helpful

I can provide a figma video @BobanStojanovski

Research the Intersection Observer API (the threshold property). It's almost certain that's what you're looking for.
